# Fallback aggregation field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I'm storing criminal records, where each record has the following form:

`{
  "ssn" :      "123-45-6789",
  "passport" : "85729573",
  "crime" :    "overpowering the guards"
}`

These records are subject to the following constraints:

- Either `ssn` or `passport`, but not both, may be missing.
- If a criminal has *any* record containing their `ssn`, then *all* their records are guaranteed to contain their `ssn`.

  - This implies that any time a record has a `passport` but no `ssn`, then
    that criminal is only known by their `passport`. However, there are criminals who have some records with only their `ssn`, and some records with both their `ssn` and their `passport`.

I would like to see the crimes grouped by each criminal, using a single query. I think the most efficient approach would be to:

1. Partition the records into two sets according to whether or not their `ssn` field is missing.
2. Aggregate the "has `ssn` set" by `ssn`
3. Aggregate the "missing `ssn` set" by `passport`

I would prefer a solution which avoids aggregating on `passport` within `ssn` buckets.

Essentially, I want to aggregate on `ssn` whenever possible, falling back to `passport` only when necessary.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create a couple of filtered aggregation. On top of my head:

```
{
  "aggs": {
     "withSsn": {
       "filter": {
         "exists": {
           "field": "ssn"
         }
       },
       "aggs": {
         "ssn": {
           "terms": {
             "field": "ssn"
           }
         }
      }
    },
    "withoutSsn": {
      "filter": {
        "missing": {
          "field": "ssn"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "passport": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "passport"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(I'm not sure what you mean by null field, I just assume that they're present or not)

Comment: That works perfectly - thank you! And yes, I meant to say that the field was missing. I've edited the post accordingly.